# find command in AIX Version 6.1

Tags: find, aix

for the following command

```
find . -name "*.java"
```

the result is what I expected, find the filename with extension .java under current directory and its subdirectory, but I cannot understand the following command output

```
find . -name *.java
```

without the double quote, I know * has special meaning in ksh, but what is this command do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many *.java files you have in the current directory:

0: the shell passes the mask to 'find': `find . -name *.java`

1: the shell passes the filename to 'find': `find . -name 1.java`

2+: the shell passes the filenames to 'find': `find . -name 1.java 2.java 3.java ...`

Of course 'find' won't know what to do with the extra filenames after the first one

Answer (score 0):

You want to give `*.java` to `find`, not something that is substituted by bash before giving the command to `find`. You can do this by putting `*.java` in double quotes, or by escaping the special characters:

```
find . -name \*.java
```

You can see what is happening with

```
set -x
find . -name *.java
set -
```